# Set initial vuetify v-select value

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

Can someone help me set the default value for a `v-select`? The caveat is that my `v-select` is populated with objects, which I think might be the reason why assigning my `item-value` to my desired initial value isn't working:

```
<v-select
  item-text="name"
  v-model="defaultSelected"
  :items="people"
>

Vue.use(Vuetify);

const vm = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    defaultSelected: {
      name: "John",
      last: "Doe"
    },
    people: [
      {
        name: "Harry",
        last: "Potter"
      },
      {
        name: "George",
        last: "Bush"
      }
    ]
  }
});
```

Expected:

The initial `v-select` should be `John`

Actual:

The initial `v-select` is blank. Here's a fiddle for reference:

https://jsfiddle.net/tgpfhn8m/734/

How can I get the behaviour I expect?

Comment: I think you should include Jhon in your 'people' array, as another option.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

I believe there are two issues with your set up. Firstly, the initial value should be one of the `options` in `select`, i.e., you should have `people` include your `defaultSelected`; Secondly ***your object needs to contain a `value` field***, see [`v-select` props](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/selects). Otherwise you need to specify `item-value` prop; See a working example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/tgpfhn8m/747/).

```
<v-select
  item-text="name"
  item-value="last"
  v-model="defaultSelected"
  :items="people"
>

Vue.use(Vuetify);

 const vm = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    defaultSelected: {
      name: "John",
      last: "Doe"
    },
    people: [
      {
        name: "John",
        last: "Doe"
      },
      {
        name: "Harry",
        last: "Potter"
      },
      {
        name: "George",
        last: "Bush"
      }
    ]
  }
});
```

Comment: Note: Array must be an object or string primitives like numbers won't work.

Answer (score 28):

Alternative answer for those finding this question from a search...

**How to select default value using an attribute of an object**

```
<template>

   <v-select v-model="input.user_id" :items="users" item-value="id" item-text="name" label="Users"/>

</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data: () => ({
        input: {
            user_id: 2,
        },
        users: [
          {
            id: 1,
            name: "John",
            last: "Doe"
          },
          {
            id: 2,
            name: "Harry",
            last: "Potter"
          },
          {
            id: 3,
            name: "George",
            last: "Bush"
          }
        ]
    }),
  }
</script>
```

**Fiddle example:** https://jsfiddle.net/4c3tbj6m/

**Explain usage:**

`v-model` is a special interfacing method for the `value` attribute of an `<input />` field.

`item-value="id"` tells the `input` field what `attribute` of a selected `object` item row to `set` as the `value` of `input.user_id`

`item-text="name"` tells the field what `attribute` of a selected `object` item row to use to display as the **selected text**.

See [Official Documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html) on `v-model`.

Example above is a `select` field so `v-model` is representing value of what would be a `selected` attribute of an `option` element like the following:

`<option value="1" selected>John</option>`

The value of `input.user_id` is the selected item (value set by the `v-model` bind)

You can then POST the entirety of `input` (if more input fields are added) but in this case there is only `user_id` in there:

```js
methods: {

  save() {

    axios.post('/my/api/example', this.input).then(response => {

      console.log(response);

    })

  }

}
```

```
<v-btn @click.prevent="save">SAVE</v-btn>
```

This will `POST` a `JSON` object to your servers end point `/my/api/example` formatted like this:

```json
{
  "user_id": 1
}
```

Comment: what does `v-model="input.user_id"` mean?

Comment: @armnotstrong Updated my answer with additional information.

Answer (score 1):

for **v-select** you should use **item-title**, **item-value** and **item-disabled** props according to the official [documentation](https://next.vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-select/).

```
<template>
    <section>
        <div>
            <label>Choose a poll:</label>
            <div>
                <v-select v-model="selected" :items="body" item-title="name" item-value="last" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</template>
<script>
  data: {
    selected: '',
    body: [
      {
        name: "Bob",
        last: "One"
      },
      {
        name: "Tom",
        last: "Dylan"
      },
      {
        name: "Mark",
        last: "Wen"
      }
    ]
  }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who stumbles upon this and needs a vue 3 composition api typescript solution for select with objects:

```
<template>
            <select v-model="state.selectedShape">
                <option
                    v-for="(shape) in state.shapes"
                    :key="shape.id"
                    :value="shape">
                    {{ shape.description }}
                </option>
            </select>
</template>


<script>
         setup () {
            const state = reactive({
                selectedShape: new Shape(),
                shapes: Array<Shape>(),
            });
         }
</script>
```

Like this you can update the shape object and array equally and all of those will be reactive.

To get an initial value what I did was this because I also insert other values from an api, but I'm sure there's better ways:

```
        state.shapes.push(new Shape());
```

Either way, I did all this because I don't want null values, and instead of `new Shape()` I actually use a default shape which has the description "All", so that when I select it I have a Shape with no actual data and an id of 0.

Answer (score -3):

just add selected:true

```
items: [
    {
      text: "Name",
      value: "name",
      selected: true,
    },
    {
      text: "Identifier",
      value: "id",
    },
    {
      text: "Episode",
      value: "ep",
    },
  ],
```