# How to set a dynamic value to a v-select, vuetify, vuejs?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a select that gets dynamically filled with the `vehiculos_usuarios` information, the array contains objects, whose values ​​are shown in the `v-select`.

What can I do to **predefine** a value in the `v-select` and **at the same time** execute the function `@change="vehiculoSeleccionado"`? This function will only be executed when making a change in the select and that is not what I want.

```
<template>
    <v-flex xs12 sm6 d-flex>
      <v-select
        :items="vehiculos_usuario"
        label="Selecciona vehiculo"
        item-text="nombre"
        item-key="vehiculos_usuario"
        item-value="id"
        return-object
        @change="vehiculoSeleccionado"
       ></v-select>
    </v-flex>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  data() {
      return {
         vehiculos_usuario: [
            {
             id: "-L_UU2Ca0hEruJ8Yxwt2"
             idcategoria: "-LWPTMu1m4WYO1wzJFiv"
             nombre: "Mazda 2019 - PP223PRL"
             placa: "P223PRL"
            },
            {
             id: "-L_UYxSRD9_1rb02fp5X"
             idcategoria: "-LWPRsmK3uBYWGeixA8E"
             nombre: "Honda - Moto - CC222RRR"
             placa: "C222RRR"
            }
         ]
     }
  },
  methods:{
   vehiculoSeleccionado(val){
    console.log("Vehiculo Seleccionado");
    console.log(val);
   }
  }
}
</script>
```

In this way you can see:

[image]

[image]

Basically I want that when starting the view the select contains a predefined value, from the `vehiculos_usuarios` information and it should look like this, at the same time executing the
function `vehiculoSeleccionado`

[image]

Thank you very much.

Comment: Probably answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51392719/set-initial-vuetify-v-select-value

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set initial vuetify v-select value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51392719/set-initial-vuetify-v-select-value)

Comment: Not fully, cause even though he was missing that also in the question, he wanted to trigger a function, which is a little more than just missing the value

Comment: I must also make the function run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a `v-model` which is the one that should contain the selected value for your example.

To fix the issue that is happening to you what you can do is make the `v-model` equal to the element that you want to display by default, and in the [`created` hook for `vue`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Instance-Lifecycle-Hooks) when the view is created, you can fire the function passing the v-model that is by default `vehiculoSeleccionado (vModelSelect)`

It could look something like this [(snippet here)](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WmdoMZ).

```html
<template>
    <v-flex xs12 sm6 d-flex>
        <v-select
                v-model="selectedItem"
                :items="vehiculos_usuario"
                label="Selecciona vehiculo"
                item-text="nombre"
                item-key="vehiculos_usuario"
                item-value="id"
                return-object
                @change="vehiculoSeleccionado"
        ></v-select>
    </v-flex>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                selectedItem: {
                    id: '-L_UU2Ca0hEruJ8Yxwt2',
                    idcategoria: '-LWPTMu1m4WYO1wzJFiv',
                    nombre: 'Mazda 2019 - PP223PRL',
                    placa: 'P223PRL',
                },
                vehiculos_usuario: [
                    {
                        id: '-L_UU2Ca0hEruJ8Yxwt2',
                        idcategoria: '-LWPTMu1m4WYO1wzJFiv',
                        nombre: 'Mazda 2019 - PP223PRL',
                        placa: 'P223PRL',
                    },
                    {
                        id: '-L_UYxSRD9_1rb02fp5X',
                        idcategoria: '-LWPRsmK3uBYWGeixA8E',
                        nombre: 'Honda - Moto - CC222RRR',
                        placa: 'C222RRR',
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        methods:{
            vehiculoSeleccionado(val){
                console.log("Vehiculo Seleccionado");
                console.log(val);
            }
        },
        created() {
            this.vehiculoSeleccionado(this.selectedItem)
        }
    }
</script>
```

You can take a look at this from the vuetify team on how to give default values to the selects https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/selects#customized-item-text-and-value