# default value for select menu

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a select menu and I pass it and object like this

```
color: [
    {value: 0, name:"red"},
    {value: 1, name:"blue"}
    ]
```

My select menu is :

```
<v-select
    label="Spectra Interpolation"
    v-model="selectedColor"
    :items="color"
    item-text="name"
    item-value="value"
    return-object
    >
</v-select>
```

In my selectedColor model, I want have the integer value of selected color 
for example if I choose red in menu , I want have 0 in my model.
I want have a default value for 0 if the menu is not used.
actually I retrieve the entire object.

thanks

Comment: Whats your question?

Comment: I want retrieve the value of the color in my model.

Comment: I think this is already answered here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51392719/set-initial-vuetify-v-select-value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you have the "return-object" attribute on the v-select.  Remove that as having that "Changes the selection behavior to return the object directly rather than the value specified with item-value"